# State-based animation for a React component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a component, `PromptBox` that I want to animate off the left side of the screen on a state change from center. Then on another state change, animate from off the right side, into the center

Here is my code for the component. I was attempting to use a `this.isActive()` function to manage the state and animation which just makes the component disappear.
**CSS:**

```
.prompt-box {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: #1E1E1E;
    width: 35%;

    -webkit-transition-property: left;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1.0;
    -webkit-transition-property: ease-in-out;
}

// before animating in (off to the right)
.prompt-box.ready {
    left: 100%;
}

// animating out to the left
.prompt-box.done {
    left: -100%;
}
```

**JS:**

```
isActive() {
    const { activity } = this.state;

    if (activity === 'done') {
        return 'prompt-box done';
    } else if (activity === 'ready') {
        return 'prompt-box ready';
    } else {
        return 'prompt-box';
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className={this.isActive()}>
            <p className='title'>What's in your future?</p>

            <ul className='options-holder'>
                {
                    this.state.items.map((item, index) => (
                        <li key={item.id} className={`option ${index === 0 ? 'first' : ''}`}>
                            <div className='circle' onClick={this.removeItem} />

                            <p className='item-text'>{ item.text }</p>
                        </li>
                    ))
                }

                <li key={0} className={`option form ${this.state.items.length === 0 ? 'only' : ''}`} ref={el => (this.formLi = el)}>
                    <div className='circle form' />

                    <form className='new-item-form' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <input 
                            autoFocus 
                            className='new-item-input' 
                            placeholder='Type something and press return...' 
                            onChange={this.handleChange} 
                            value={this.state.text}
                            ref={input => (this.formInput = input)} />
                    </form>
                </li> 
            </ul>

            <button className='confirm-button' onClick={this.submitAndContinue}>Continue</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: do you have a fiddle for it?

Comment: I don't. Was hoping this would be enough

Comment: Here's a non-working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wjrrsx5w/. Not sure how to get a fiddle working with React

Comment: ok thx! when you in devtools try to add the class ready to your div , can you see their properties  of .prompt-box.ready? if not this could be a type in your css! If you write pure css only using "/* comment */" is permitted

Comment: or only just remove the two comments in your css and check if it works

Comment: Yeah, if I add the `.done` class, the element will disappear from the screen but with no animation. Devtools will show it has having a left value of 100%

Comment: ok and when you just replace the 3 lines of transition with this one: transition: left 0.3s ease-in-out 0s; ?

Comment: Oh I see :-) you wrote -webkit-transition-property two times! so this will rewrite the property set to left through ease-in-out

Comment: oh, whoops! let me try fixing that 1 sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so update your css to this:

```
...
-webkit-transition-property: left;
-webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
```

Comment: glad I could help! I know this when you's deep in your code and overlook small things ;-)